# How to find mode of multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

Input column example :

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cat | cat | cat | dog |
| dog | dog | cat | dog |
| bird | cat | cat | dog |
| bird | bird | cat | dog |

Output column example :

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Mode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cat | cat | cat | dog | cat |
| dog | dog | cat | dog | dog |
| bird | cat | cat | dog | cat |
| bird | bird | cat | dog | bird |

So far I have only calculated mode for a single column. Not sure how we can do it horizontally by combining 4 columns.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html) with select first column by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for first mode value per rows:

```
df['Mode'] = df.mode(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
print (df)
  Column A Column B Column C Column D  Mode
0      cat      cat      cat      dog   cat
1      dog      dog      cat      dog   dog
2     bird      cat      cat      dog   cat
3     bird     bird      cat      dog  bird
```